How to access to the current set of arguments from the scenario’s examples in cucumber in Typescript?
I have a cucumber feature file, where I am passing data through scenario outline example.
I wanted to read those examples/parameters in hook.ts-->After() method (typescript). How to access current set of data of a scenario?
I tried pickle, picklestep, but not able to find the proper solution.
